# React HOC and TypeScript 3.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

As TypeScript improve its JSX type-checking in v3.2, we have a problem to correctly type our HOCs now.

Can someone fix types in the following HOC for TypeScript 3.2?

```
import { ComponentType } from 'react';

type Props = { custom: string };
type Omit<T, K extends string> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

function hoc<P extends Props>(Component: ComponentType<P>) {
  return (props: Omit<P, keyof Props>) => {
    return <Component {...props} custom="text" />;
  }
}
```

TypeScript error:

```
Type '{ custom: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
Property 'custom' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

Basically, the idea is to transform the component which requires "custom" property to component, which doesn't need it anymore as it will be injected automatically by HOC.

EDIT:
Probably the same issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28748

Comment: I have the same exact issue with the new TS 3.2.1, I think that it is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this is not the answer that you were hoping for, but you can make it work by changing the type of `props` in the inner function to `any`, and putting the `Omit` type in the return type annotation of the outer function, like this:

```
function hoc<P extends Props>(Component: ComponentType<P>): ComponentType<Omit<P, keyof Props>> {
  return (props: any) => {
    return <Component {...props} custom="text" />;
  }
}
```

Comment: I postponed the casting of `props` to `any` until the spread, so I used `{(...this.props as any)}`, so you can still work with the typed `props` elsewhere in the render function. So far, the most unintrusive solution. Thanks...

Comment: The problem with this answer, is that you are returning a component will no typechecking on its props

Answer (score 0):

Here's an HoC that supports forwarding refs as well along with a jest test.

Ther is only one `as` and that's the part where I convert the input props to props used by the wrapped component since they can be different.

Note the `T` can be any because React-Native vs React JS differ on how to provide the constructor.  [What is the `T` type argument in ReactElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74697170/what-is-the-t-type-argument-in-reactelement) is a related question as to what the `T` is.

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { ComponentType, forwardRef, NamedExoticComponent, PropsWithoutRef, ReactElement, Ref, RefAttributes, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, TextProps } from 'react-native';

/**
 * This is a simple HoC that is a noop that supports ref forwarding.
 * @param Component component to wrap
 * @param options options for the HoC building
 * @typeParam P the exposed props of the higher order component
 * @typeParam Q the props for the wrapped component
 * @typeParam T type for ref attribute of the wrapped component
 * @typeParam O options for the HoC building
 * @returns A named exotic componentwith P props that accepts a ref
 */
function hoc<P, Q, T, O = {}>(Component: ComponentType<Q>, options?: O): NamedExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>> {
    function wrapped(props: P, ref: Ref<T>): ReactElement<Q> {
        // the an unknown as Q here is an example, but P and Q can be different.
        const componentProps: Q = props as unknown as Q;
        return <Component {...componentProps} ref={ref} />
    }
    const displayName =
        Component.displayName || Component.name || "AnonymousComponent";
    wrapped.displayName = displayName;
    return forwardRef(wrapped);
}

describe("hoc", () => {
    it("should work with text", () => {
        const HocText = hoc<TextProps, TextProps, Text>(Text);
        const { toJSON } = render(<HocText>simple string</HocText>);
        const { toJSON: expectedToJSON } = render(<Text>simple string</Text>)
        expect(toJSON()).toStrictEqual(expectedToJSON())
    });

    it("should pass ref for text", () => {
        const callback = jest.fn();
        const HocText = hoc<TextProps, TextProps, Text>(Text);
        function MyComponent() {
            const textRef = useRef<Text>(null);
            useEffect(() => {
                callback(textRef?.current)
            }, []);
            return <HocText ref={textRef}>simple string</HocText>
        }

        const { toJSON } = render(<MyComponent />);
        const { toJSON: expectedToJSON } = render(<Text>simple string</Text>)
        expect(toJSON()).toStrictEqual(expectedToJSON())
        expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(callback.mock.calls[0][0]).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should work the same way with normal Text", () => {
        const callback = jest.fn();
        function MyComponent() {
            const textRef = useRef<Text>(null);
            useEffect(() => {
                callback(textRef?.current)
            }, []);
            return <Text ref={textRef}>simple string</Text>
        }

        const { toJSON } = render(<MyComponent />);
        const { toJSON: expectedToJSON } = render(<Text>simple string</Text>)
        expect(toJSON()).toStrictEqual(expectedToJSON())
        expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(callback.mock.calls[0][0]).toBeTruthy();
    });


});
```