# What is the `T` type argument in ReactElement?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the `T` type argument in ReactElement? I can tell from the body it's used for `type`,

```
interface ReactElement<P = any, T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> {
  type: T;
  props: P;
  key: Key | null;
}
```

but I am not sure what I would put in there.  For example, if I have a [higher-order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) (HOC) that does nothing but forwards the references:

```
import { ComponentType, forwardRef, NamedExoticComponent, PropsWithoutRef, ReactElement, Ref, RefAttributes } from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { Text, TextProps } from 'react-native';

/**
 *
 * @param Component component to wrap
 * @param options options for the HoC building
 * @typeParam P the exposed props of the higher order component
 * @typeParam Q the props for the wrapped component
 * @typeParam T type for ref attribute of the wrapped component
 * @typeParam O options for the HoC building
 * @returns A named exotic componentwith P props that accepts a ref
 */
function hoc<P, Q, T, O = {}>(Component: ComponentType<Q>, options?: O): NamedExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>> {
    function wrapped(props: P, ref: Ref<T>): ReactElement<Q> {
        // The unknown as Q here is an example, but P and Q can be different.
        const componentProps: Q = props as unknown as Q;
        return <Component {...componentProps as Q} ref={ref} />
    }
    const displayName =
        Component.displayName || Component.name || "AnonymousComponent";
    wrapped.displayName = displayName;
    return forwardRef<T, P>(wrapped);
}

describe("hoc", () => {
    it("should work with text", () => {
        const HocText = hoc<TextProps, TextProps, typeof Text>(Text);
        const { toJSON } = render(<HocText>simple string</HocText>);
        const { toJSON: expectedToJSON } = render(<Text>simple string</Text>)
        expect(toJSON()).toStrictEqual(expectedToJSON())
    });
});
```

The above works, but what's a more restrictive version I can put in
`ReactElement<Q,???>`, but still make it compile?

Comment: (At least [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74697170/what-is-the-t-type-argument-in-reactelement/74697285#74697285) (now deleted) was generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned/421867#421867).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T is either one of the built-in JSX elements or a custom functional/class component. For React stuff, like `div`, `input`, etc. Read *[parameters for *createElement()](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/createElement#parameters)*.

> type: The type argument must be a valid React component type. For example, it could be a tag name string (such as 'div' or 'span'), or a React component (a function, a class, or a special component like Fragment).

I believe something like this should suit your needs. I changed several things

- `ReactElement<Q>` -> `ReactElement<Q, typeof Component>`
- `P extends Q` in generic

  - This one is totally optional, since React will discard extraneous properties anyway
- `wrapped` function to `wrapped` anonymous function will allow us to type this

  - Allows `wrapped.displayName = 'foobar'` to still work but disallows stuff like `wrapped.foobar = true`

```js
function hoc<P extends Q, Q, T, O = {}>(
  Component: ComponentType<Q>,
  options?: O
): NamedExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>> {
  const wrapped: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P> = (
    props: P,
    ref: Ref<T>
  ): ReactElement<Q, typeof Component> => {
    return <Component {...props} ref={ref} />;
  };
  const displayName =
    Component.displayName || Component.name || 'AnonymousComponent';
  wrapped.displayName = displayName;
  return forwardRef<T, P>(wrapped);
}
```

Now, as far as I know, there is no/little point to typing the return of any functional component, because JSX is not statically analyzed by TypeScript beyond knowing that it is a JSX element.

```js
const test = <Component {...props} ref={ref} />
// ^ regardless of any component, as long it is is JSX it will
// be of type `JSX.Element`, which is just `React.ReactElement<any, any>`
```

So you can end up using the incorrect ReactElement anyway...

```js
  const wrapped: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P> = (
    props: P,
    ref: Ref<T>
  ): ReactElement<Q, typeof Component> => {
    return <></>; // no errors?
  }
```

So this is just as suitable:

```js
function hoc<P extends Q, Q, T, O = {}>(
  Component: ComponentType<Q>,
  options?: O
): NamedExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>> {
  const wrapped: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P> = (
    props: P,
    ref: Ref<T>
  ): JSX.Element => {
    return <Component {...props} ref={ref} />;
  };
  const displayName =
    Component.displayName || Component.name || 'AnonymousComponent';
  wrapped.displayName = displayName;
  return forwardRef<T, P>(wrapped);
}

// And even more strict
function hoc<
  P extends Q,
  Q extends {},
  T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> =
    | string
    | JSXElementConstructor<any>,
  O = {}
>(
  Component: ComponentType<Q>,
  options?: O
): NamedExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>> {
  const wrapped: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P> = (
    props: P,
    ref: Ref<T>
  ): JSX.Element => {
    return <Component {...props} ref={ref} />;
  };
  const displayName =
    Component.displayName || Component.name || 'AnonymousComponent';
  wrapped.displayName = displayName;
  return forwardRef<T, P>(wrapped);
}
```

Anyway, here's a good [Q&A: When to use JSX.Element vs ReactNode vs ReactElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement) with further reading.

You could use `React.createElement` instead of JSX as well, but there isn’t any difference aside from typing depth. Besides it'll be more of a headache than it is worth, since these are all implementation details for you and not any end user.

Comment: whoa... P extends Q works?

Comment: the string | JSXElementConstructor<any> won't satisfy React Native Text so likely the T needs to be any to support other react frameworks.